# Suppress WARN and DEBUG in jboss log

Tags: jboss5.x

Im using jboss5 with mysql. im getting lot of entries in WARN,DEBUG. So its hard to search for errors when something went wrong.
Can we suppress WARN and DEBUG entries from jboss log that coming from
org.jboss.resource , org.jboss.remoting, org.jboss.ejb3.

i have edited jboss-log4j like,

```
<category name="org.jboss.resource">
<priority value="WARN"/>
</category>
```

bud didnt work. not sure how to edit that properly. can anyone shed some light.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you did is indeed correct, that tells JBoss to show only WARN and upper (ERROR, FATAL) log levels for that category, you should do that as well with the other categories

If it's not working, check which appender (console, file, etc) is configured and how